# How to create a WPF project without using Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-code

How can I create (and run) a new WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) project without having Visual Studio installed? My primary editor is VS code but it does not have the feature for creating new projects from templates?

Comment: In shor, you are asking for a VS Code tutorial

Comment: VS Code's site explains [how to work with C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp).  Microsoft's Docs site contains many tutorials, eg [Getting started with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/getting-started/with-visual-studio-code).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos None of those links talk about starting a WPF project. I don't think it can be done very easily at the moment.

Comment: @Kurren this is a `Getting Started` question, not a question about WPF specifically. The OP asked how to create a class library *and* WPF project. That's the reason for the downvotes - simply googling would have provided the answer. Those getting started links *do* point to a class library project

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question title says it clearly: WPF project.

Comment: @OlegMihailik read the question again. It asks how to create projects in general, not just WPF. `2- How to create Class Library`. If one can't even create a class library project, one should look for an introductory tutorial *first*.

Comment: @OlegMihailik besides, judging from the accepted answer, the OP probably didn't even know the difference between VS Code and Visual Studio.

Comment: The question is about WPF and plain library, so the answer should cover that. It's not about helping one person, it's about everybody coming across the same problem. I for once am interested in using VSCode with WPF too.

Comment: [vscode-wpf](https://github.com/Bigsby/vscode-wpf)

Comment: @OlegMihailik I tried for a whole day messing all sort of extensions to make this work. For now, I'd say forget it. The experience is broken and non-functional for the most basic stuff and I'm not even talking about debugging or compiling. Use VS2017 until yhere is a better option. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VS Code is designed more to host Console based apps such as .Net Core, .Net Framework Console, and Node.js. If you would like to develop WPF apps look for a different solution. I highly recommend using [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft.

Comment: well, it's not true

Comment: @FoggyFinder while not entirely as you can by really messing with extension heavily, it is still far from ideal and probably is the qorse experience of coding for WPF. Visual Studio is far better even though itsalso far more intensive on hardware but VS2017 fixed most of that but reducing by a whole lot the ressources needed.

Comment: @Johnny Prescott yeah, I agree that VS seems like better choice for WPF, but I don't like the next part "Visual Studio Code cannot be used for WPF development". It can.

Answer (score 3):

write in terminal "dotnet new" and check the list. Class library is at "dotnet new classlib", but I'm interested in how to create WPF applications too, because there isn't that comand in the list.

Comment: https://github.com/Bigsby/wpf-vscode I haven't tried it but I think cloning this and doing the steps mentioned in `README.md` should work at debug and editing a WPF project. Unfortunately I don't think you can create/initialise a WPF project outside of visual studio or there are not tools to do that yet...

Comment: That's interesting! I'll have to check it out.

Comment: .NET 5.0 has WPF support. Simply write `dotnet new wpf`.